# Not able to use JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I added the dependency for JpaRepository that is

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I extend it I am still getting red underline saying

```
The type org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

What to do?

Comment: update your local repository

Comment: Did maven clean, update maven, build project option. Still error

Comment: I think your dependency is not updated properly so that you are getting the `cannot be resolved`

Comment: Yeah. But what to do as I already updated.

Comment: It gives a quick fix saying 'configure build path'

Comment: I am using maven on eclipse haven\t installed it to use from command line